# How to execute a main class in a jar from gradle using the 'java' command

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I have these files under the `<project_root>` folder:

```
./build.gradle
./build/libs/vh-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
./libs/groovy-all-2.1.7.jar
./src/main/groovy/vh/Main.groovy
```

In the `build.gradle` file, I have this task:

```
task vh( type:Exec ) {
    commandLine 'java -cp libs/groovy-all-2.1.7.jar:build/libs/' +
            project.name + '-' + version + '.jar vh.Main'
}
```

The `Main.groovy` file is simple:

```
package vh

class Main {
    static void main( String[] args ) {
        println 'Hello, World!'
    }

}
```

After plugging in the string values, the command line is:

```
java -cp libs/groovy-all-2.1.7.jar:build/libs/vh-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar vh.Main
```

If I run the command directly from shell, I get correct output. However, if I run `gradle vh`, it will fail. So, how do I make it work? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Exec.commandLine` expects a *list* of values: one value for the executable, and another value for each argument. To execute Java code, it's better to use the `JavaExec` task:

```
task vh(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "vh.Main"
    classpath = files("libs/groovy-all-2.1.7.jar", "build/libs/${project.name}-${version}.jar")
}
```

Typically, you wouldn't have to hardcode the class path like that. For example, if you are using the `groovy` plugin, and `groovy-all` is already declared as a `compile` dependency (and knowing that the second Jar is created from the `main` sources), you would rather do:

```
classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
```

To find out more about the `Exec` and `JavaExec` task types, consult the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: Better solution than official documentation.